# VBA(MSWord): cant find Bullet points with a specific rgb color

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to count all bullet points in a text consisting of three different colored bullets which are not index colors but costume RGBs (*e.g.* 51, 204, 204). And then want to display how many were of each color (*e.g.* 42 with blue)
So came up with this but doesn't compile and says "invalid qualifier" pointing to ".Font" which i highlighted in the code:

```
Sub GetNumberOfBullets()

   Dim objRange As Range
   Dim objParagraph As Paragraph
   Dim nNumber As Integer

   '  Initialization
   Set objRange = Selection.Range
   nNumber = 0
   cyannum = 0
   purplenum = 0
   greennum = 0

   For Each objParagraph In objRange.Paragraphs
   If objParagraph.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then
     nNumber = nNumber + 1
     If objParagraph.Range`.Font`.Color.RGB = RGB(51, 204, 204) Then
        cyannum = cyannum + 1
        End If
     If objParagraph.Range`.Font`.Color.RGB = RGB(204, 153, 255) Then
        purplenum = purplenum + 1
        End If
     If objParagraph.Range`.Font`.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
        greennum = greennum + 1
        End If
     End If
   Next objParagraph

   '  Pop up a message box to show the total number of bullets.
   MsgBox ("Bullet number:" & nNumber & "Cyan number:" & cyannum & "Purple number:" & purplenum & "Green number:" & greennum)
 End Sub
```

Comment: This is a maze! My advice is not to go there. Basically, the font for the bullet is specified differently and separately from the font of the text. There is a myriad of objects, some of them not accessible the way you might expect, none of them well documented and no documentation at all about how they work together. If you insist, the best help I found is available at http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not `Font` that the compiler is objecting to but `Color`. When looking for the font colour of a `Range` you need to look at the `Fill` properties.

If you adjust your code to `objParagraph.Range.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB` you will then be able to compile your code.

I take it from your code that you are looking for the colour of the text that follows the bullet and not the bullet character? If you are looking for the colour of the bullet character then please see the comment from Variatus.

Comment: you got it right!! i needed the color of the text that comes after the bullet. but in most cases the starting bullet character matches the color so didn't felt the need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The comment made by @Variatus is absolutely correct. There are a variety of ways of colouring a bullet point and you'd need to know what the author has done before writing your code.

It is possible to colour a bullet point by highlighting a paragraph and colouring the text. The bullet point will adopt the colour of your last, ie paragraph, character. If the paragraph contains multiple colours then the `Paragraph.Font.Color` property will return 'all the 9s', so your best bet would be to test the colour of the last character.

Assuming this is the way you want to test the bullet point colour - and that's a BIG assumption - then the problem with your code lies not in the `Font` property but in the fact that `RGB` is not a property of `Color`. `RGB()` is a function that returns a long from your RGB values, so you need to compare the `Color` value with `RGB(r,b,g)` according to the following syntax:

`If ... .Font.Color = RGB(r, b, g) Then`

Your corrected code would therefore be something like this:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim myCyan As Long, myPurple As Long, myGreen As Long
Dim cyanCount As Long, purpleCount As Long, greenCount As Long

myCyan = RGB(51, 204, 204)
myPurple = RGB(204, 153, 255)
myGreen = RGB(0, 176, 80)

Set rng = Selection.Range
For Each para In rng.Paragraphs
    With para.Range
        If .ListFormat.ListType = wdListBullet Then
            Select Case .Characters.Last.Font.Color
                Case myCyan: cyanCount = cyanCount + 1
                Case myPurple: purpleCount = purpleCount + 1
                Case myGreen: greenCount = greenCount + 1
            End Select
        End If
    End With
Next

MsgBox "Cyan=" & cyanCount & ", " & _
       "Purple=" & purpleCount & ", " & _
       "Green=" & greenCount
```